# SetWindowHookEx() returns NULL

Tags: windows, winapi, null, set, hook

I'm trying to create an application that will be notified about each active window change in Windows so it could do some tasks like detecting window titles, therefore "punishing" bad people accessing bad content on our PC machines. So, this is really important for the application because it's purpose is to log "bad" applications from history.

So, in my main function, I started a thread for my `WindowLogger`.

```
windowThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) WindowLogger,
        (LPVOID) argv[0], 0, NULL );

if (windowThread)
{
    // Also a bit of protection here.. 
    return WaitForSingleObject(windowThread, INFINITE);
}
```

Then, here is my `WindowLogger` procedure:

```
// Function called by main function to install hook
DWORD WINAPI
WindowLogger(LPVOID lpParameter)
{

    HHOOK hWinHook;

    HINSTANCE hExe = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    if (!hExe)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        hWinHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, (HOOKPROC) CBTProc, hExe, 0);

        MSG msg;

        // I AM UNSURE ABOUT THIS PART.. 
        // Probably wrong code :D .. 

       while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
        {
             if (msg.message == HCBT_ACTIVATE) {
                // my code to log the window name
            }
        }
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hWinHook);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And finally, my `CBTProc` callback function, it logs the windows using my `log()` function:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK
CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (nCode)
    {

    case HCBT_ACTIVATE:
    {
        HWND foreground = GetForegroundWindow();
        char window_title[50];
        if (foreground)
            GetWindowText(foreground, window_title, 25);

            log("|");
            log(&window_title[0]);
            log("|");  

        }
    }
}
```

So I had debugged the program and what I figured out is that `hWinHook` becomes `NULL` after `SetWindowsHookEx()` -- this is what probably causes my program to mailfunction.. 
.. Can you help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, describe Windows version and state of UAC.

Comment: Waste of time. "Bad" people may use non-message pump application or use kernel mode driver or something else.

Comment: Nick K - Windows 10 x64, UAC - default ( Notify me when apps try to make changes to my computer ). user2120666 - i know this is not the best method, but I am satisfied with this concept

Comment: @user2120666: I suspect the OP means users running applications they aren't supposed to, or accessing inappropriate websites, rather than malicious applications.  This still isn't the best approach (group policy application whitelisting and/or proxying) but it is certainly much easier.

Comment: Note that there is hardly ever any point in creating a thread and then immediately waiting for it to exit.  Your main function might as well just call WindowLogger directly.

Answer (score 2):

Passing `0` for the `dwThreadId` parameter to `SetWindowsHookEx` is used to register a hook for all threads in the system, i.e. a global hook. However to do this, your hook code needs to be located within a DLL (so that the DLL can be mapped into the address space of other processes). Since your hook code is in your main executable rather than a DLL the call is failing.